# Does the $scope object is shared across all controllers when using nested controllers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can we have nested controllers in AngularJS? In the case of nested controllers, does the $scope object is shared across all controllers.

**The problem is :-**

I can access the first controller $scope values across the all controllers but I can't get the second controller scope objects in third controller. You can run and check it in this below snippet.

```js
 var app = angular.module("appTest",[]);


    function Controller1($scope) {
      $scope.text1= "text Sample 1"
    }

    function Controller2($scope) {
      $scope.text2= "text sample 2"
    }
    
    function Controller3($scope) {
      $scope.text3 = $scope.text1 + " And " + $scope.text2;
    }

    app.controller("Controller1",Controller1);
    app.controller("Controller2",Controller2);
    app.controller("Controller3",Controller3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="appTest">
    <div ng-controller="Controller1">
      <div>
      <h1> First Controller</h1>
        First Controller Values is <b> {{text1}}</b>
      </div>
      <div ng-controller="Controller2">
       <h1> Second  Controller</h1>
        First Controller Values is <b> {{text1}}</b>
        <br />
        Second controller value is <b> {{text2}}</b>
      </div>
       <div ng-controller="Controller3">
       <h1> Thired  Controller</h1>
        First Controller Values + Second controller value  is <b> {{text3}}</b>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#user-content-ng-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can have nested controllers in angularjs. The parent controllers scope will be inherited down the prototypical chain and all child controllers will have access to parent's scope.

> But I can't get the second controller scope objects in third controller.

The reason is your third controller is independent of your second controller. You cannot access the `$scope` property from another independent controller directly. You can either nest your third controller inside the second one or use a service to share data (latter is more preferred).

```js
var app = angular.module("appTest",[]);


    function Controller1($scope) {
      $scope.text1= "text Sample 1"
    }

    function Controller2($scope) {
      $scope.text2= "text sample 2"
      $scope.text1="text Sample 1 from controller 2";//this will be printed in controller 2 and if you want to access parent data, use $parent
    }
    
    function Controller3($scope) {
      $scope.text3 = $scope.text1 + " And " + $scope.text2;
    }

    app.controller("Controller1",Controller1);
    app.controller("Controller2",Controller2);
    app.controller("Controller3",Controller3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="appTest">
    <div ng-controller="Controller1">
        <div>
            <h1> First Controller</h1> First Controller Values is <b> {{text1}}</b> </div>
        <div ng-controller="Controller2">
            <h1> Second  Controller</h1> First Controller Values is <b> {{$parent.text1}}</b>
             First Controller's scope objects value in scond controller <b> {{text1}}</b>
            <br /> Second controller value is <b> {{text2}}</b>
            <div ng-controller="Controller3">
                <h1> Thired  Controller</h1> First Controller Values + Second controller value is <b> {{text3}}</b> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```